# .NET Core 3 Worker Service Settings Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, worker

I have the following successfully working in .NET Core 2, but it doesn't work in .NET Core 3.

I've made a new Worker Service .Net Core 3 project from scratch and added only the minimum to recreate my error.

Here is my entry point in *Program.cs*

```
namespace WorkerService1DeleteMe
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.Configure<ConfigChunk>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ConfigChunk"));
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }

    public class ConfigChunk
    {
        public string Server { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So there is a single line added to `CreateHostBuilder` here, to the `Configure` method, and a new `ConfigChunk` class at the bottom, to match the schema of a section in *appsettings.json*.

Finally, an extension of the parameters to the Worker constructor to let it consume the SettingsChunk:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly ConfigChunk _config;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, ConfigChunk config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

As alluded to, this works fine in NET Core 2, but in 3 it fails with:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'WorkerService1DeleteMe.ConfigChunk' while attempting to activate 'WorkerService1DeleteMe.Worker'.

I feel like I am missing something blindingly obvious but must confess I am at a loss. What I have observed is that I can make the whole thing work by going `services.AddSingleton` instead of `services.Configure` but I much prefer the pattern and reload functionality of the Configure approach if I can make it work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Few options are available.

With current configuration update worker to use `IOptions<TOptions>`

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly ConfigChunk _config;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IOptions<ConfigChunk> config) {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config.Value;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Or leave the worker as is and update the configuration to allow the class itself to be injected.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
                services.Configure<ConfigChunk>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ConfigChunk"));
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddTransient<ConfigChunk>(_ => _.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ConfigChunk>>().Value);

            });
```

The second example will allow for explicit injection of the `ConfigChunk` while still allowing the options features to be in effect and does not tightly couple the worker to framework concerns.

Comment: Woop, thats fantastic mate thank you very kindly, works a treat!

Comment: This helped me inject a status object into a combined worker/webapi project that enabled the worker service status information to be exposed via the webapi.  Thank you.

Comment: So I was using:
IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
Configuration appConfiguration = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<Configuration>();
services.AddSingleton(appConfiguration);

This works fine for me, when I switch it to use IOptions like in your example

services.Configure<Configuration>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

It's not loading my AppSettings section from appSettings.json.  What am I missing here?  Also does this support appSettings.Development.json and appSettings.Production.json, what about file reload on change?

Comment: I was able to answer my own question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609652/net-core-3-worker-service-dependency-injection-configuration-by-ioptions?noredirect=1&lq=1

Look at the .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config)  section this answered all my questions about optional and reload and also got mine working.