# Get appsettings.json values on .net core 3.0 worker service after publish as windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Following the answer:
[.NET Core 3 Worker Service Settings Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288674/net-core-3-worker-service-settings-dependency-injection/58305931#58305931)

I can get the settings in Debug or in Release, at class Worker.cs
But when deployed as Windows Service, this values return as null

Worker.cs

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly ServiceSettings _serviceSettings;
    private readonly ServiceConfigurations _serviceConfigurations;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IOptions<ServiceConfigurations> serviceConfigurations, IOptions<ServiceSettings> serviceSettings) 
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceConfigurations = serviceConfigurations.Value;

        _logger.LogInformation($"Worker running at: {DateTime.Now}");
        _serviceSettings = serviceSettings.Value;

        string retornoPathLog = null;
        string PathLog = _serviceSettings.PathLog;

        if (!Directory.Exists(PathLog))
        {
            retornoPathLog = "Diretório de LOG " + PathLog;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(PathLog);
        }

        //Configure Serilo for Logging
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File(PathLog + "log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retornoPathLog) == false)
        {
            Log.Information("[WFoneService - Watch Event] " + retornoPathLog);
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WFoneConnection": ""
  },
  "ServiceConfigurations": {
    "UrlSignalrNotification": "urlValue",
    "WatchIp": "ipValue",
    "WatchPort": "portValue"
  },
  "ServiceSettings": {
    "PathLog": "C:\\Log\\"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show startup code for windows service.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to handle this.

1. you can use the dotnet new worker template

`dotnet new worker`

2. Manually change your project type to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker in your .csproj

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">`

3. In your .csproj add your appsettings.json file and have it copied to the output directory

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

If you have an existing project I'd recommend #2 convert your csproj to us the Worker Sdk, alternatively if its simple to just create a new project use #1.  #3 is a terrible hack just to copy out the appsettings.json file to your output, I don't recommend this.

Comment: Do you have any links to documentation showing that the Worker SDK does include appsettings.json files by default?

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of experience with .NET core 3.0, I stopped adding a package to the project, and following a documentation from the Microsoft website I found the solution.
I solved the problem as follows

In the Program.cs file, I added .UseWindowsService () and added the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices package as documented in the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: this solved my issue. I missed: ```Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices``` and ```.UseWindowsService()``` I wasted 3 hours on this.... I thought after create a Worker Service project, I would be able to start running the webservice. It does run when testing with VS, but after added the exe and starting the exe in the Services window in Windows 10, it always said, Error1503 not respond timely....