# .NET Core 3 Worker Service Dependency Injection Configuration by IOptions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, backgroundworker

i have a question about DI on Worker Service that answered another post below.

[.NET Core 3 Worker Service Settings Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288674/net-core-3-worker-service-settings-dependency-injection/58608830#58608830)

what if i want to add some helper class and registered as below. 
How can i use that option injection. 
because i think, i missed something...

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
            {
                // Configure the app here.
                config
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                Configuration = config.Build();

            })

            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {

                services.AddOptions();               

                services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));                    


                services.AddSingleton<RedisHelper>();

                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();                   

            });
    }
```

RedisHelper class has a constructor like this as Worker.

```cs
public static MySettings _configuration { get; set; }

public RedisHelper(IOptions<MySettings> configuration)
{
    if (configuration != null)
        _configuration = configuration.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to build the config yourself. You can access it in the ConfigureServices via the `hostContext`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) {
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) => {
            // Configure the app here.
            config
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {

            services.AddOptions();               

            services.Configure<MySettings>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
            services.AddSingleton<RedisHelper>();
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); 
        });
}
```

Now it is just a matter of injecting the options into the desired helper class

```
//...

public RedisHelper(IOptions<MySettings> configuration) {
    if (configuration != null)
        _configuration = configuration.Value;
}

//...
```

and the Worker service

```
public Worker(RedisHelper helper) {
    this.helper = helper;
}
```